# Scoreboard teams gets cleared when a player moves

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-spigot

Players are removed from their scoreboard team on my Spigot server as soon as they move (this includes changing the direction in which they look).

I run this command:

```
/scoreboard teams join TeamName @p
```

and then, without moving, this command:

```
/scoreboard teams list TeamName
```

I get listed as though I am in the team properly:

```
Showing 1 player(s) in team TeamName:
<my username>
```

Then, I'll move my player, and run the same command again:

```
/scoreboard teams list TeamName
```

I get a message saying the following:

```
Team TeamName has no players
```

The above^ also happens if I add myself to the team, move, and then list the players in the team. It only lists me *until* I move. It happens to *all* teams.

I should also note that one of the plugins appears to be creating a team named `collision`, which automatically adds players to it. It re-appears even after I remove it. I have no clue as to which plugin is creating this team, and have no way to tell without deleting each plugin individually.

Server Plugins (1.12, run on Aternos):

- OldPvP (maybe this one?)
- BloodEffects (maybe this one?)
- Citizens
- InstantRespawn
- Multiverse-Core
- NickNames (maybe this one?)
- WorldEdit
- WorldGuard

Comment: Did you try adding the plugins one by one so you can investigate which plugin is causing this issue?

Comment: I just did this, and it turns out that OldPvP was the culprit. I'm finding a new plugin for that now.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft" in the help-center](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. Outside of those, modded issues are on-topic.

Comment: @galacticninja "or other abnormal behavior caused by modding". This looks like one of them.

Comment: @pinckerman "The abnormal behavior" wording is too subjective, and broad. If the game runs fine without crashing, I don't consider it off-topic as per the discussion in those meta posts I linked above, especially in [What exactly is technical support?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797) (see top-voted answer).

Comment: @galacticninja I got your point, but since it's still subjective I feel it's not wrong to VTC. That phrase needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out. The OldPvP plugin was overwriting the scoreboard teams, causing the issue. I've deleted the plugin and installed OldCombatMechanics instead; works like a charm.